# Ordering of Angular e2e describe and it blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, end-to-end, karma-runner

I'm using Karma to run an e2e test in AngularJS.

Within a `describe()` block, why are `it()` blocks always executed **after** any nested `describe()` blocks regardless of their order in the test?

For example:

```
describe( 'Hello Page Nav Bar', function()
{
    it( 'should be on the hello page', function()
    {
        expect( browser().location().url() ).toBe( '/hello' );
    } );

    // ... many other it() blocks relating to 'Nav Bar' ...

    // Create nested describe specifically for menu items within the nav bar
    describe( 'Nav Bar Menu Items', function()
    {
        it( 'should have 12', function()
        {
            expect( element( '.menu-items div' ).count() ).toBe( 12 );
        } );

        // ... many other it() blocks relating to 'Nav Bar Menu Items' ...
    } );
});
```

Will end up executing in this order:

```
* Hello Page Nav Bar
   *  Nav Bar Menu Items
      *   should have 12
   * should be on the hello page
```

It would make sense that I'd want to test *"should be on the hello page"* before anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree.

A workaround is to always keep the describe block containing only other "describe blocks" or only "it blocks". This way, the order is kept coherent.